# Interprocess communication betwenn java and c++ via process stream

Tags: java, c++, process

i want communication between java and c++ process using java output/input stream

on the java side

```
public void test() throws IOException {

       ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe");
       builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
       process = builder.start();
       OutputStream prO=process.getOutputStream();
       InputStream prI=process.getInputStream();

       prO.write(("dir \n").getBytes()); //write to processs stream
       prO.flush();
}
```

but how c++ side should look ?

Comment: Use the stdin/stdout see this c++ - c++ example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779462/c-stream-input-process

Comment: thank you it worked